# Gmail marks all my emails sent by exim4 as spam

Tags: email, debian, exim

I configured a Virtual Private Server as send-only mail server with exim4. Anyway, when I send an email to a Gmail account, it is marked as spam, because "it violates the guidelines for the sender recommended by Google.".

I checked if my domain name isn't blacklisted, and it isn't.

I also create a record A with my domain which I used as reverse DNS for my VPS.

I can't figure out the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2696779

Answer (score 1):

You also need to be sure you have valid DKIM and SPF records setup for your domain. You can create a `TXT` record that looks like this:

```
google._domainkey
```

So fully resolved that would be `google._domainkey.yourdomain.com.`

Now for DKIM, you need to find your key in googles admin dashboard for your email: `v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=y; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCG5in7gQIDAQAB`

See more details here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/174126?hl=en

> note that string will be a lot longer.

Comment: I saw that you need a Google Apps account... which isn't free... it it true?

Comment: @BillBall No you don't need a Google Account. See the questions and answer (duplicate) linked above.